# git-tfs clone fails with error code 128

Tags: git, tfs, git-tfs

I'm using git-tfs to clone a TFS repository, something I've been able to do successfully in the past.  But with the current version when I run the command, like this...

`git tfs clone http://NameOfOurTfsServer:8080/ $/NameOfMyProject -d`

...I get an error code 128, e.g.:

> `System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> Sep.Git.Tfs.Core.GitCommandException: Command exited with error code: 128
>      at Sep.Git.Tfs.Core.GitHelpers.Close(Process process) in c:\Users\matt\dev\github\git-tfs\GitTfs\Core\GitHelpers.cs:line 205
>      at Sep.Git.Tfs.Core.GitHelpers.<>c__DisplayClass8.<CommandOutputPipe>b__7() in c:\Users\matt\dev\github\git-tfs\GitTfs\Core\GitHelpers.cs:line 59 [etc.]`

This is on git-tfs 14.0.  I've tried several previous versions of git-tfs, but I get the same or similar errors on each one.

Has anyone run into this?  Do you know a fix?

Comment: I saw this a few days ago cloning a very large repo (took over 48 hours to get everything) with git-tfs 0.17. I was running the following: `git tfs clone <tfs> --rebase` Several times it bombed out with error 128. The first few times I just ran the same command again and it picked up where it left off. Later I switched to `git tfs fetch` which seemed to be more reliable for some reason (though it was almost done by then anyway).

Comment: I ended up switching to git-tf, which has steadily improved and does everything I need (when I'm stuck in a TFS shop).

Answer (score 0):

I have had issues like this, especially when the TFS server *drops* the connection. My **workaround** has been to delete the folder and run the same command again.

You may try [quick-clone](https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs/wiki/Clone) instead of [clone](https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs/wiki/Clone), since it will finish faster. I am assuming that you don't need the full history.

Comment: If that's due to the fact that the tfs Server drop the connection during a long clone, you could test, instead of doing a new clone to do:
git tfs cleanup
and then git tfs fetch (to continue the clone...)

Answer (score 0):

That's probably too late, but for future reference it's important:
Go to the Windows Credentials and remove all the credentials bound to TFS Git.
It worked for me.